# Write Procedure [OR] Query for Insert with Ignore using 3 Composite keys from excel or csv file in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

how to write procedure or query to insert data from excel to mysql table with 3 composite keys combination and make sure that using these 3 composite keys combination for no duplicates to be insert into mysql table from excel.

The data exported from Oracle database with primary key as ID but the new database table i.e mysql not having the Primary key as ID  and It having 3 primary (composite) keys.

```
Table Fields:

ID (this is primary key in Oracle DB , it is auto increment filed)

I_ID

ENTITY_ID

TYPE_ID

CODE

VALUE


New database(Fields are same but ID is not primary key) : 

ID 

I_ID

ENTITY_ID

TYPE_ID

CODE

VALUE

PRIMARY KEY - I_ID,ENTITY_ID & VALUE.
```

Can anyone please suggest to write procedure or query to validate or remove duplicates with combination of composite key as I_ID,ENTITY_ID & VALUE and insert into MySQL Table from excel or suggest if any other approaches also for the same?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with removing duplicates I would extract to csv and use load data infile https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html (section Duplicate-Key Handling) using the ignore option to discard duplicates.